# The name of month goes to January when I try to input it as number. It works fine when I input as text

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, angular6

The name of month goes to January when I try to input it as number. It works fine when I input as text (using angular and momentjs)

```html
<input
    matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"
    placeholder="{{sqlParamsItem.parmPrompt}} dd MMM yyyy"
    [(ngModel)]="fromDate"
    [formControl]="date"
    class=""
    required
    (dateChange)="addEvent('change', $event)"
>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please edit your question to explain better?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani i implement a date picker using angular material as shown in the angular material date picker examples. it is working absolutely fine but the problem is when i try to input the date as number 03 04 2018 the result should 03 Apr 2018 but it give me 03 Jan 2018, whatever i input it goes to January. [Note] you can find the similar example in angular date picker example the last one in there examples. thanks

Comment: Can you show us the Component code? specially addEvent('change', $event) method

Comment: @Output() dateChange = new EventEmitter<MatDatepickerInputEvent<string>>();